# Android error testing picture service and location service with Gluon Mobile

Tags: gluon-mobile, javafxports

I'm testing the barcodescanservice, the locationservice and the pictureservice in a simple BasicView with 3 buttons. The barcodescanservice is ok, but the pictureservice produces a nullpointer error in AndroidPicturesService.java:132. The positionservice an AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. In the two cases the program breaks.

I'm using org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16 and com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2. Tested in Android 4.4.4 and Android 8.0 with the same result. The code is copied from the Api Doc.

The code:

```
        Button butFoto = new Button("Photo");
        butFoto.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Services.get(PicturesService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
                    service.takePhoto(false).ifPresent(image -> imageView.setImage(image));
                });

            }
        });

        Button butBarcode = new Button("Barcode");
        butBarcode.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String barcodeValue = Services.get(BarcodeScanService.class)
                        .flatMap(service -> service
                        .scan("Scan Test", "Place a barcode under the camera", "Barcode found with value"))
                        .orElse("No barcode found");
                System.out.println("Scanned Bar Code: " + barcodeValue);
                label2.setText(barcodeValue);
            }
        });

        Button butGPS = new Button("Position");
        butGPS.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Services.get(PositionService.class)
                        .ifPresent(positionService -> {
                            positionService.start();
                            ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Position> positionProperty = positionService.positionProperty();
                            Position position = positionProperty.get();
                            label2.setText("Lat=" + String.valueOf(position.getLatitude())
                                    + " Lon=" + String.valueOf(position.getLongitude()));
                        });
            }
        });
```

Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.cip.cipgesfx" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>

    <application android:label="cipmobile" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/cip_icono">
        <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="CipMobile" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.cipmobile.Cipmobile"/>
            <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.scan.zxing.CaptureActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
                  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                  android:stateNotNeeded="true"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android.scan.SCAN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PermissionRequestActivity" />

        <service android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.AndroidPositionBackgroundService" 
                 android:process=":positionBackgroundService" />

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Build Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.cip.cipgesfx.IniciarApli'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:2.6.3'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa', version: '2.7.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx
    compile group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.14'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.9.8'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'barcode-scan', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'pictures', 'position', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize '3g'
        }
        androidSdk='/home/cesar/Android/Sdk'
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
            exclude 'license.html'
            exclude 'readme.html'
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'NOTICE.txt'
            pickFirst 'META-INF/eclipse.inf'
        }
        compileSdkVersion=21
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Stacktrace error for picture service:

```
04-21 19:31:13.678 5482-5514/com.cip.cipgesfx I/GLASS: Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
04-21 19:31:13.678 5482-5514/com.cip.cipgesfx I/GLASS: Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
04-21 19:31:13.678 5482-5514/com.cip.cipgesfx I/System.out: don't add points, primary = -1
04-21 19:31:13.688 5482-5514/com.cip.cipgesfx I/AndroidPicturesService: Picture file: file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20190421_193113.jpg
04-21 19:31:13.708 5482-5514/com.cip.cipgesfx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
    Process: com.cip.cipgesfx, PID: 5482
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:584)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:558)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
        at com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android.AndroidPicturesService.takePicture(AndroidPicturesService.java:132)
        at com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android.AndroidPicturesService.takePhoto(AndroidPicturesService.java:95)
        at com.cipmobile.BasicView$2.lambda$handle$1(BasicView.java:50)
        at com.cipmobile.BasicView$2$$Lambda$1.accept(BasicView.java)
        at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:154)
        at com.cipmobile.BasicView$2.handle(BasicView.java:49)
        at com.cipmobile.BasicView$2.handle(BasicView.java:46)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
```

Stacktrace error for location service:

```
04-21 19:33:28.648 5544-5568/com.cip.cipgesfx I/AndroidPositionService: Available location providers on this device: [passive, gps, network].
04-21 19:33:28.648 5544-5568/com.cip.cipgesfx I/AndroidPositionService: Picked network as best location provider.
04-21 19:33:28.648 5544-5568/com.cip.cipgesfx I/AndroidPositionService: Location provider network is not enabled, starting intent to ask user to activate the location provider.
04-21 19:33:28.668 5544-5568/com.cip.cipgesfx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
    Process: com.cip.cipgesfx, PID: 5544
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1112)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1093)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:311)
        at com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android.AndroidPositionService.initialize(AndroidPositionService.java:179)
        at com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android.AndroidPositionService.start(AndroidPositionService.java:110)
        at com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android.AndroidPositionService.start(AndroidPositionService.java:99)
        at com.cipmobile.BasicView$4.lambda$handle$0(BasicView.java:75)
        at com.cipmobile.BasicView$4$$Lambda$1.accept(BasicView.java)
        at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:154)
        at com.cipmobile.BasicView$4.handle(BasicView.java:74)
        at com.cipmobile.BasicView$4.handle(BasicView.java:70)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
```

I expect the camera to open when clicking the Photo Button but an exception arises. The same when clicking the GPS Button.

Comment: Pictures: See [JavaDoc](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/PicturesService.html), you need to add a `FileProvider`. About GPS, see [JavaDoc sample](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/PositionService.html)

Comment: Thank you, @JoséPereda. I have updated the code and now runs perfectly on Android 8. But on Androind 4.4.4 fails the camera after clicking ok and the position service in service.start. Does Gluon Mobile execute on level < 21 ?

Comment: Gluon Mobile should work, but Charm Down library (the one with the native services) might fail due to invalid Android API under level 21. You can check the library [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/25153dd50a22565f0efa437e68145417abfcd952?at=default). `adb logcat` will definitely tell you what is failing.

Answer (score 0):

For all the newbies like me, I write down the correct code and configuration. It runs ok on Android 8.

```
public class BasicView extends View {

    final Label lblPosition;

    public BasicView() {
        System.setProperty("com.gluonhq.charm.down.debug", "true"); //*********************** ATTENTION

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        //setting the fit height and width of the image view 
        imageView.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView.setFitWidth(200);
        //Setting the preserve ratio of the image view 
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        lblPosition = new Label("Auto");

        Label lblBarcode = new Label("Barcode");
        Label lblManualPosition = new Label("Manual Position");

        Button butExit = new Button("Exit");
        butExit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Services.get(LifecycleService.class).ifPresent(lifecycle -> {
                    lifecycle.shutdown();
                });
            }
        });

        Button butPhoto = new Button("Photo");
        butPhoto.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Services.get(PicturesService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
                    service.takePhoto(false).ifPresent(image -> imageView.setImage(image));
                });

            }
        });

        Button butBarcode = new Button("Barcode");
        butBarcode.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                String barcodeValue = Services.get(BarcodeScanService.class)
                        .flatMap(service -> service
                        .scan("Scan Test", "Place a barcode under the camera", "Barcode value:"))
                        .orElse("No barcode found");
                System.out.println("Scanned Bar Code: " + barcodeValue);
                lblBarcode.setText(barcodeValue);
            }
        });

        Button butGPS = new Button("Position");
        butGPS.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Services.get(PositionService.class)
                        .ifPresent(service -> {
                            service.positionProperty().addListener(
                                    (obs, ov, nv)
                                    -> {
                                lblManualPosition.setText("Lat=" + String.valueOf(nv.getLatitude())
                                        + " Lon=" + String.valueOf(nv.getLongitude()));
                                //System.out.printf("Current position: %.5f, %.5f",nv.getLatitude(), nv.getLongitude()));
                            });
                            service.start();
                        });
            }
        });

        VBox controls = new VBox(5);
        controls.getChildren().addAll(imageView, lblPosition, lblBarcode, lblManualPosition, butExit, butPhoto, butBarcode, butGPS);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setCenter(controls);

        if (!Services.get(PositionService.class).isPresent()) {
            lblPosition.setText("No GPS avalilable");
        } else {
            lblPosition.setText("Found GPS");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> System.out.println("Menu")));
        appBar.setTitleText("Basic View");
        appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.SEARCH.button(e -> System.out.println("Search")));
    }

}
```

The build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.16'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.prufx.Prufx'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'barcode-scan', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'pictures', 'position', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize '3g'
        }
        compileSdkVersion=28
        androidSdk='/home/cesar/Android/Sdk'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Then AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.prufx" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application android:label="prufx" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="prufx" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.prufx.Prufx"/>
            <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.PermissionRequestActivity" />

        <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.scan.zxing.CaptureActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
                  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                  android:stateNotNeeded="true"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android.scan.SCAN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.AndroidPositionBackgroundService" 
                 android:process=":positionBackgroundService" />

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.prufx.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>    

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: In which directory should I put this  AndroidManifest.xml: file I am running on my project on IntellJ